# Two Contexts in a ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, dbcontext, multiple-databases

I've this structure:

[image]

**PGDbContext.cs code:**

```
namespace Inspeccions.Models
{
    public class PGDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public PGDbContext() : base( "ActivitatsEntities") { }
        public virtual DbSet<activitats_activitat> Usr { get; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
    }
}
```

**ModelInspeccions.Context.cs code:**

```
namespace Inspeccions.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class InspeccionsEntities : DbContext
    {
        public InspeccionsEntities()
            : base("name=InspeccionsEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Criteri> Criteris { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CriterisInspeccio> CriterisInspeccios { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CriterisTipusInspeccio> CriterisTipusInspeccios { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Inspeccio> Inspeccios { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<TipusInspeccio> TipusInspeccios { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Usuari> Usuaris { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Web.config code:**

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ActivitatsEntities" connectionString="Server=***;port=5432;Database=sitsalt;     User Id=***;Password=***" providerName="Npgsql" />
  <add name="InspeccionsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ModelInspeccions.csdl|res://*/Models.ModelInspeccions.ssdl|res://*/Models.ModelInspeccions.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SLTPANOLI;initial catalog=Inspeccions;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" support="FF" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

**ActivitatsController code:**

public class ActivitatsController : Controller
{
    PGDbContext _context;

```
public ActivitatsController()
{
    _context = new PGDbContext();
}

// GET: Activitats
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(_context.Usr.ToList());
}
```

If I create a project with only one of the connections and context it works, but when I put it in the same project the ModelInspeccions work but the PDGbContext returns a null DbSet...

Can anyone help me please? Thanks!

Comment: Did you forget to declare the DBSets for your PGDbContext or did you just omit that from your posted example?  And pleas remove your explicit do connection information from the posted webconfig.

Comment: Thanks @TravisActon the connection is not the correct one and is internal, but much better not to put it, thanks ;)

Comment: I've added the controller :)